# Is on-device image recognition possible with dynamic images?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, image-recognition, arcore

One question about Image Recognition in AR SDKs. Is it mandatory that the target images should be part of the app itself or can we have set of images in the app memory and perform on-device image recognition with it (the images might change or download when we click on a button each time in the app) ? note: The use case is only Image recognition and not the AR feature

Comment: Is this possible in both ARcore and ARKit ?

Answer (score 2):

You might have noticed that the class you use to load images from your app bundle and provide them to ARKit for detection is [`ARReferenceImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arreferenceimage).

Scroll down the docs page for that class and you’ll find, in addition to a method for loading reference images, two initializers for Creating Reference Images at runtime:

- [The `CGImage`-based initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arreferenceimage/2942252-init) is good for cases where you’re loading image content from elsewhere, like fetching from the user’s Photos library or downloading from a server.
- [The `CVPixelBuffer`-based initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arreferenceimage/2942251-init) is good for cases where you have image content that’s already in GPU memory — say, if you wanted to extract a portion of ARKit’s [`capturedImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2867984-capturedimage) for use in image detection.

---

There’s one caveat to all this, though. When you put images in your asset catalog at build time, Xcode preflights them to make sure both that each individual image is good for detection and that the whole set of images are distinct enough from each other to be recognized reliably.

If you’re providing images dynamically, you don’t get that preflighting step, which creates design/interaction issues you’ll need to solve yourself:

- If *you* control the dynamic images (e.g. they’re all downloaded from your servers), you can do the preflighting “offline” using a dummy Xcode project.
- If you allow *users* to provide or create any possible image, you’ll need to design your app around the possibility of a user choosing images that don’t detect well.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Rickster.. any idea whether the same is possible in ARCore for android mobiles ?